# Get a file content in Bash after expanding its variables

Tags: bash, variables, quoting

**cat file**

```
$VAR
```

**cat script**

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTENT=$(<file)
echo $CONTENT
```

**./script**

```
$VAR
```

I'd like to get the variable's actual value, not "$VAR". How to get a weaker quoting? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CONTENT=$(eval echo -e `<file`)
```

Comment: +1 You don't really need that extra `cat` process, though. Read from stdin by replacing `\`cat file`\` with `$(<file)`

Comment: Even if file contains newlines or even \n's, the result of this command wouldn't. How can we preserve newlines?

Comment: @AndreyRegentov I came up with this: `while read line; do eval echo $line; done <file`